# Bash string concatenation asking for numeric argument

Tags: string, bash, function

I need a bash function that prefixes a date_time string with a string.

`show_neb_2017_05_20_16_55`

My current function I am hoping would have done this, except that it is requiring a numeric argument.

```
    function show_neb() {
        a='show_neb_'$(date +"%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M")
        return $a
        }

    echo $(show_neb)
```

I would have expected it to work, but it isn't.  Isn't this just a direct standard output to a string?

Comment: The point you are missing is `return` only returns success/failure, not a string. to do what you were attempting, try `echo "$a"; return 0;`

Answer (score 2):

`return` can only be used to provide an integer exit code for the function, not an arbitrary string value. To simulate a return value, you need to write to standard output, then capture that via a command substitution.

```
show_neb () {
    date +"show_neb_%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M"
    # Replacing echo "show_neb_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M")"
}

val=$(show_neb)
```

Shell functions really aren't functions in the usual sense; they are more like in-memory shell scripts that are sourced.

Comment: Just running the function would do what they want.

Comment: Yes; I'm emphasizing what you would need if you want to assign the "return value" to a variable.

Comment: Making good use of the `date` output within the function rather than an explicit `echo` or `printf` `:)`  (of course in this case, you can get rid of the `show_neb` function altogether and just use command substitution on the `date` command itself)